# TypeScript error when using conditional types with React components

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm encountering a TypeScript error when using conditional types with React components.

The issue arises when trying to render different types of components based on a type prop and providing the corresponding props for each type.

```
type PairingCardProps = {
  p: string;
};

type SampleCardProps = {
  s: string;
};

export const GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS = {
  pairing: ({ p }: PairingCardProps) => <div>Pairing Card</div>,
  sample: ({ s }: SampleCardProps) => <div>Sample Card</div>,
};

type TypefaceGridCardProps =
  | ({ type: "sample" } & SampleCardProps)
  | ({ type: "pairing" } & PairingCardProps);

const TypefaceGridCard = ({ type, ...props }: TypefaceGridCardProps) => {
  const Card = GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS[type as keyof typeof GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS];

  if (!Card) return null;

  return <Card {...props} />;
};
```

The error I encounter is as follows:

`Type PairingCardProps is missing the following properties from type 'SampleCardProps': s`

#### Workaround

I work around this issue by type casting but find the object map solution above preferable.

```
type TypefaceGridCardProps =
  | ({
      type: "pairing";
    } & PairingCardProps)
  | ({
      type: "sample";
    } & SampleCardProps);

const TypefaceGridCard = ({ type, ...props }: TypefaceGridCardProps) => {
  switch (type) {
    case "sample":
      return <SampleCard {...(props as SampleCardProps)} />;

    case "pairing":
      return <PairingCard {...(props as PairingCardProps)} />;

    default:
      throw new Error(`Unknown type: ${type}`);
  }
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure why exactly I get this error, but I was able to make it work with `Card(props)` notation, not with JSX. You can check it out [here](https://tsplay.dev/mLvDbw). Does this approach work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @wonderflame Really like what you did there with the TypeMap! Bit baffled by why invoking Card with regular js notation doesn’t throw. 

I’d be interested to see if there’s a way to get it to work with jsx that im missing

Comment: no idea why it is not working with JSX...

Comment: Currently, the approach with TypeMap is actually the only way of doing it, but maybe I have to define components in type a bit differen

Comment: I found a solution, will write it down soon

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is unable to handle the "correlated union types" described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581), however, there is a suggested refactor described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109), which considers moving to generics.
First, we will need some map type that will hold props of every component:

```
type PairingCardProps = {
  p: string;
};

type SampleCardProps = {
  s: string;
};

type TypeMap = {
  sample: SampleCardProps;
  pairing: PairingCardProps;
};
```

Now, let's redefined `GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS` using [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) with using `TypeMap` as a source for types:

```
export const GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS: { [K in keyof TypeMap]: React.FC<TypeMap[K]> } = {
  pairing: ({ p }) => <div>Pairing Card</div>,
  sample: ({ s }) => <div>Sample Card</div>,
};
```

Let's also define the type of the `GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS` which we will need afterwards:

```
type GridCardComponents = typeof GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS;
```

We should also create a mapped type for arguments of `TypefaceGridCard`, which will accept an option generic argument `K` that extends the key of `TypeMap` and is defaulted to `keyof TypeMap`. This type will return the props for the given `K` or a union of all possible props:

```
import {ComponentProps} from 'react';
// ...
type TypefaceGridCardProps<T extends keyof TypeMap = keyof TypeMap> = {
  [K in T]: { type: K } & ComponentProps<GridCardComponents[K]>;
}[T];
```

Let's apply our types to the `TypefaceGridCard`:

```
const TypefaceGridCard = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(props: TypefaceGridCardProps<T>) => {
  const Card = GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS[props.type];

  if (!Card) return null;

  Card(props); // no error
  
  return <Card {...props} />; // unexpected error
}
```

Strangely, we get an error when we try to invoke the component in JSX format. I'm not sure about the exact reason, but I think it has to do something about React's internal generic types, which can't properly handle such cases.

The workaround is to manually type `Card` as `FC<TypeMap[K]>` and define another variable for props that is typed as `ComponentProps<typeof Card>` and has a value of `props`:

```
const TypefaceGridCard = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(props: TypefaceGridCardProps<T>) => {
  const Card: FC<TypeMap[T]> = GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS[props.type];
  const correctlyTypedProps: ComponentProps<typeof Card> = props;

  if (!Card) return null;

  return <Card {...correctlyTypedProps} />; // no error
};
```

Alternatively, you could use `as` assertion instead of creating another variable, but I wouldn't recommend it, since it is less type-safe:

```
const TypefaceGridCard = <T extends keyof TypeMap>(props: TypefaceGridCardProps<T>) => {
  const Card: FC<TypeMap[T]> = GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS[props.type];

  if (!Card) return null;

  return <Card {...(props as ComponentProps<typeof Card>)} />; // no error
};
```

[Link to StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-9te9ka?file=src%2FApp.tsx)

Comment: Interesting problem. I managed to make the problem go away by altering the `TypefaceGridCardProps` definition like so: `[K in keyof TypeMap]: { type: K } & React.ComponentProps<GridCardComponents[K]> & JSX.LibraryManagedAttributes<K, any>;`. I can't for the life of me figure out what the proper second type parameter should be instead of `any`. Seems to be expecting React component props, but `any -> React.ComponentProps<GridCardComponents[K]>` doesn't work

Answer (score -1):

I think this us due to typescript as typescript compiler is not able to infer the `Card` component in the `TypefaceGridCard` component. I also face this type of issue . So this can be solved as  :

```
import React from "react";

type PairingCardProps = {
  p: string;
};

type SampleCardProps = {
  s: string;
};

export const GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS = {
  pairing: ({ p }: PairingCardProps) => <div>Pairing Card</div>,
  sample: ({ s }: SampleCardProps) => <div>Sample Card</div>,
};

type TypefaceGridCardProps =
  | ({ type: "sample" } & SampleCardProps)
  | ({ type: "pairing" } & PairingCardProps);

const TypefaceGridCard = ({ type, ...props }: TypefaceGridCardProps) => {
  const Card = GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS[type as keyof typeof GRID_CARD_COMPONENTS];

  if (!Card) return null;

  return <Card {...props as any} />;
};

export default TypefaceGridCard;
```